# How to specify classes from another projects to an applet?

Tags: java, applet

I have 2 projects: my main project in which the applet is, and a second project from which I use some classes. I added the second project to my main projects build path. But when I run my applet in Chrome, it gives an error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: chapter13/MessagePanel`. `chapter13/MessagePanel` is the class that I imported from the second project into my main project.

I call the applet like this(the html file is in the main project root folder):

```
<applet
      code = "myapplets/DisplayMessageApp.class"
      width = 250
      height = 50>
</applet>
```

What can I do so that the applet can see the "chapter13/MessagePanel" class from the second project?

Comment: *"main project root folder"*  All of this futzing with the IDE becomes irrelevant by time of deployment.  At that time, the classes need to be on the run-time class-path (specified in HTML) of the applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is to bundle all the required classes in a jar file and then specify this as the archive.

Like this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html
André